# Prove this fact about holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f \colon \mathbb{D} → \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. Then I want to show that the diameter 
$$d=\sup _{z, w∈\mathbb{D}} |f (z) − f (w)|$$

of the image of $f$ satisfies $2|f′(0)| ≤ d$ and that equality holds precisely when $f$ is linear, this is $f(z) = a_0 +a_1z$.

Then I did the following:

Using Cauchy's integral formula we get that,

$$2|f′(0)|=\left|\frac{1}{2πi}∫_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)−f(−z)}{z^2}\,dz\right|.$$

Then I parametrize the circle, so arrive at:

$$\frac{1}{2πi}∫_{0}^{2 \pi}\frac{f(Re^{i \theta})−f(−Re^{i \theta})}{R^2e^{2i \theta}}iRe^{i \theta}\,d\theta.$$

So given that $R=1$ and that the length of the curve is $2 \pi$ we arrive to this inequality

$$\left|\frac{1}{2πi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\frac{f(Re^{i \theta})−f(−Re^{i \theta})}{R^2e^{2i \theta}}iRe^{i \theta}\,d\theta\right|< \sup \left|f(e^{i \theta})−f(−e^{i \theta})\right|$$

and for the equality we see that if $f$ is linear then $2f'(0)=2a_0$ and $d=\sup|a_1(z-w)|=a_1$, but the thing there is no reason to have that $a_0=a_1.$

So Am I right in the first approach (or how can I fix it)? Also, how Can I get the equality?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your mistake: you say $2f′(0) = 2a_0$ when $2f′(0) = 2a_1$.

Comment: But $f(z)=a_0+a_1z $ right? so ....

Comment: Yes, and $f'(z) = a_1$.

Comment: jajajajaj right :) I was blind jajaja, and what do you think of the first part?

Comment: Is OK (but change the $<$ for $\le$). See http://manetheren.bigw.org/~ray/diampblm.pdf for an alternative proof.

Comment: Right :) So all the argument is well performed right? or something to improve, change?

Comment: The argument is OK. Another minor point: missing $|\cdot|$ in the the RHS of the Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: Rigth :), in the integral right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$2\left|f'(0)\right|=\sup_{z,\omega \in \mathbb{D}} \left|f(z)-f(\omega)\right|$ implies that $f$ is linear.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619008/2-leftf0-right-sup-z-omega-in-mathbbd-leftfz-f-omega-right)